# Flask deploy on Windows using Apache 24 and WSGI gives ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, windows, apache, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy a Flask server on Windows machine (Company policy).
It's simple project following file structure:

- app.py    /* Main flask app*/
- db        /* folder for dbConnector file */

  - dbConnector.py
- static
- templates
- myenv
- wsgi_scripts

  - gamonweb.wsgi

It works fine when I run it as Flask server.
When I try to deploy it, it returns:

```
File "C:\\GamonWeb\\gamonweb\\app.py", line 5, in <module>\r

from db import dbConnector as dbConnector\r

 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'\r
```

The import part from app.py is: from db import dbConnector as dbConnector

I had this issue with flask module but that I was able to resolve with pip install flask. As this is my own file, how can I modify it to make it work?
Thank you!